# What if I didn't finish my niyat?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sin

I kept niyat for various reasons.I kept niyat of praying so much rakat of prayers. But I haven't completed yet. What will the problems if I didn't complete my niyat after a long time? Will Allah forgive me? Or I have complete it? will my prayers will be accepted even if I didn't complete my niyat after a long time. Will I get heaven?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information on our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: This is a very vague information. Niyyah should be made before starting a deed anything else in Arabic is rather an intention (Arabic: qasd or 'azm) for which the statement of the famous hadith doesn't apply. Whether you will go to heaven doesn't depend on your niyyah of a specific deed, but on your deeds in general good and bad and whether Allah accepted them. You should clarify what was your intention and where do you fail to accomplish it and why. Note that if for example your niyyah differed from that of the imam in the prayer the majority considers your prayer as valid anyhow.